# Why are `scope`-oriented actions (particularly `index` actions) treated differently in Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I am writing with respect to https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes

I am under the impression that *authorization* should answer the question *Are you allowed access to this resource?*, i.e. a `true`/`false` answer. This is the case with all actions except `index`, which, according to Pundit's docs, should return different `ActiveRecord::Relation`'s depending on who is asking. For example, an *admin* gets `scope.all`, while a *regular user* gets `scope.where(:published => true)`.

**app/policies/post_policy.rb**

```
class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
  def resolve
    if user.admin?
      scope.all
    else
      scope.where(:published => true)
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = policy_scope(Post)
end
```

My reservation is that this is a slippery slope, and soon I will be adding presentation to the scopes (e.g. `scope.all.order('created_at ASC')`) -- and it just feels weird doing so in an *authorization policy*.

Of course I could move that to the controller...

```
def index
    @post = policy_scope(post)
    if user.admin?
        @post = @post.order( 'created_at ASC' )
    end
end
```

...but is that the controller's job? And I don't think it would be right to add such a call to the view. So maybe it should be a model method?

What would you say are the pros/cons of doing the following instead?

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

This keeps `index` just like the other methods, with one call to `authorize`, and one call to a model method.

```
def index
  authorize(Post)
  @posts = Post.index(current_user)
end
```

**app/policies/post_policy.rb**

This simply gives a true/false answer. Are you authorized? Yes or no.

```
def index?
    user.admin? || user.regular_user?
end
```

**app/models/post.rb**

And in the model we can get as fancy as we like.

```
def self.index(user)
  if user.admin?
    Post.all.order('created_at ASC')
  else
    Post.where(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 12):

My understanding of authorization vs scopes in Pundit is as follows:

`authorization`: 'is this user allowed to **act upon (create/update/destroy)** this resource?'

`within scope` : 'should this user be able to **see (index/show)** this resource?'

Authorization (`authorize @resource`) defers to `permitted_attributes` in `ResourcePolicy` for the answer.

Scopes (`policy_scope(Resource)`) defer to `resolve`.

I believe the reasoning behind Pundit's scopes is that there should be only one location in your code where you define who should have access to what resources.

You could, as you've described, implement the same behavior in your controllers or your views. However, putting the code into a Policy guards against unauthorized access should you happen to forget to scope appropriately in one of your controller methods.

I think of `policy_scope()` as the way to restrict visibility, while other result refinements (e.g. sorting) can take place at the controller level. There's no doubt a lot of personal preference at play, however.

Comment: It seems more to me like authorize is for checking if user has permission to access an individual resource, whereas scoping is for filtering what gets returned in a index action, i.e. scoping doesn't raise a 403 forbidden error like authorize does, it's just used to strip away records that are not owned by current_user.

Comment: Even Pundit's official github page has this: `def show
  @user = authorize User.find(params[:id])
end` https://github.com/elabs/pundit