# Pundit scoping usage empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

Suppose I have a scenario where we have `Users` and each user can create their own `Projects`.

I'm trying to limit the `Show` action of my Rails controller to only allow admin or the owner of the project to be able to go through `Show` action.

The problem I am facing is, perhaps I'm misunderstanding on how to use Scopes in Pundit.

My `Show` action looks like this:

```
  def show
    project = policy_scope(Project).find_by({id: project_params[:id]})

    if project
      render json: project
    else
      render json: { error: "Not found" }, status: :not_found
    end
  end
```

My Pundit Scope class looks like this:

```
  class Scope < Scope

    def resolve
      if @user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        # obviously, if non-matching user id, an ActiveRelation of  
        # empty array would be returned and subsequent find_by(...) 
        # would fail causing my controller's 'else' to execute
        # returning 404 instead of 403
        scope.where(user_id: @user.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

In my Rails test, I am trying to assert that non-project owner should receive a 403 forbidden:

```
test "show project should return forbidden if non admin viewing other user's project" do
  # "rex" here is not the owner of the project
  get project_path(@project.id), headers: @rex_authorization_header
  assert_response :forbidden
end
```

My test is failing. I am getting the error:

```
Failure:
ProjectsControllerTest#test_show_project_should_return_forbidden_if_non_admin_viewing_other_user's_project [/Users/zhang/App_Projects/LanceKit/Rails_Project/LanceKit/test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:40]:
Expected response to be a <403: forbidden>, but was a <404: Not Found>.
Expected: 403
  Actual: 404
```

I don't quite feel like I'm using Pundit correctly.

Should I be using Pundit's `authorize project` instead of using `policy_scope(Project)...` for the `Show` action?

I was expecting the `scope.where(...)` to detect the incorrect user id and return some error saying 'you are not authorized to view this resource' rather than returning results.

Comment: I also found this Stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172620/why-are-scope-oriented-actions-particularly-index-actions-treated-differen The answer by Rob seems to suggest using scope for index/show actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what my test results are indicating to me, using scope for `show` action is **wrong**.

My finding is telling me Pundit scope are only used for filtering a set of data to only return those that matches a condition, it does NOT check whether the current_user is the owner of the resource. Pundit scope does NOT raise a `403 Forbidden` error.

In other words, using scoping only in the `show` action will lead to a semantic bug that's saying `this project with id 3 does not exist in the database` for example instead of saying `you are not authorized to view this project because it belongs to a different user`.

A summary for myself:

- use `policy_scope` for `index` action
- use `authorize` for `show`, `create`, `update`, `delete`
- use `authorize` AND `policy_scope` if you're not resource owner and trying to access some funky plural resource route like

  `get "/user/1/projects" => "Project.index"`

  in case you want to check if user is say a "project manager" or "collaborator" who is allowed to view your project. In this case, you would probably need to modify your scope code with an extra `elsif` clause.

In relation to my above question, I modified my project to use `authorize` inside my `show` action:

```
def show
    project = Project.find_by({id: project_params[:id]})

    authorize project

    if project
      render json: project
    else
      render json: { error: "Not found" }, status: :not_found
    end
  end
```

This then raises the expected 403 Forbidden error that my tests is expecting and thus my test passes.

Comment: I agree with this, when accessing a show you are asking for a specific record. Pundit scopes make sense only for an index (or other collection method).

Answer (score 0):

[Pundits docs regarding scopes](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes) state that you can indeed use them for the show action:

```
def index
  @posts = policy_scope(Post)
end

def show
  @post = policy_scope(Post).find(params[:id])
end
```

Just using `authorize` may not be enough if a User (manually) opens a URL with a id param of an instance, that she should not be able to view.

To avoid a `RecordNotFound` error, I used the [recommended `NilClassPolicy`](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#nilclasspolicy):

```
class NilClassPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      raise Pundit::NotDefinedError, "Cannot scope NilClass"
    end
  end

  def show?
    false # Nobody can see nothing
  end
end
```